# What is test(0) in this snippet from kotlinlang.org?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, kotlin

I'm trying to solve the problem of "runs" in the KotlinKoans page [here](https://try.kotlinlang.org/#/Examples/Problems/Runs/Runs.kt)

Here is my implementation

```
package runs

fun runs(a: IntArray): Int {
    var numberOfRuns = 1;

    for (index in 0..a.size-2) {
        if (a[index+1] != a[index]) numberOfRuns++
    }

    return numberOfRuns
}
```

Here is the test suite that runs against the implementation

```
class Tests {

    @Test fun testRuns1() {
        test(0)
    }

    @Test fun testRuns2() {
        test(1, 1)
    }

    @Test fun testRuns3() {
        test(3, 1, 2, 3)
    }

    @Test fun testRuns4() {
        test(3, 1, 2, 2, 3)
    }

    @Test fun testRuns5() {
        test(3, 1, 1, 2, 3)
    }

    @Test fun testRuns6() {
        test(1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
    }

    @Test fun testRuns7() {
        test(3, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1)
    }

    @Test fun testRuns8() {
        test(3, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1)
    }

    @Test fun testRuns9() {
        test(5, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1)
    }
}

fun test(expected: Int, vararg data: Int) {
    assertEquals(expected, runs(data), "\ndata = ${Arrays.toString(data)}")
}
```

All test passes except testRuns1(), I don't understand what test(0) does, given that the test() function takes two parametrs as input, an expected value and the actual value. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second argument of test is a vararg which means it can take 0 to many Integers. Hence a call to test(0) has expected = 0 and data = an empty vararg list.

The call to runs(data) then just returns 1 since the list is empty and the for loop has nothing to loop through.

**EDIT:** Although now I think about it. This means this test would fail since its asserting that expected number of runs should be 0 but it's going to come back as 1 as far as I can tell.

Comment: Ok Thanks! So here 0 is the expected value and it's passing an empty array, with this correction at the top: 
 if(a.isEmpty()) return 0 
it passed all tests